# How can I log AFHTTPRequestOperationManager request?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

I'm having some trouble with RESTfull web service and I'm trying to see my request as a text using NSLog. I tried this:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
...
 [manager POST:urlString parameters:mutableParameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
...
   } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Response:  %@", [operation description]) ;
        if (block) {
            block(error);
        }

        NSLog(@"-------------------------------");
        NSLog(@"Request: %@", manager.requestSerializer.debugDescription);
        NSLog(@"-------------------------------");
        NSLog(@"Request: %@", manager.requestSerializer.description);
        NSLog(@"-------------------------------");
        NSLog(@"Request: %@", operation.request.HTTPBodyStream);
        NSLog(@"-------------------------------");
        NSLog(@"Request: %@", operation.request);
        NSLog(@"-------------------------------");
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        NSLog(@"-------------------------------");

}];
```

Is there any way to NSLog the request from AFHTTPRequestOperationManager (AFNetworking 2) ?

Comment: Maybe the request is _not_ failing? Can you debug into either the success or failure blocks?

Comment: My problem is that the server is saying I have a null field in the request (json format). But I added a breakpoint to check the value. It's not null. So I thought maybe the problem was in the request structure...

Comment: So the server doesn't send back a response?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look to the POST method:

```
 [manager POST:urlString parameters:mutableParameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
```

You have a `AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation` and an `id responseObject` in the success block.

The best thing that you can do is to put a:

```
NSLog(@"AFHttpRequestOperation %@", operation);
```

and set there a breakpoint so you can inspect what's happening there:

[image]

What do you want to see about the operation's request?

Not exactly logging but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394289/nsurlrequest-to-nsstring) explains how to convert NSURLRequest to NSString

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My problem is that the server is saying I have a null field in the request (json format). But I added a breakpoint to check the value. It's not null. So I thought maybe the problem was in the request structure...

Comment: If you are sending json to the server have a look to setting the request serializer to json type.